# checksum accepted result

Tags: sql-server, checksum

I am calculating checksum in a stored procedure :

```
CHECKSUM_AGG(checksum(cid,tableid, sid, pid, vid, Tablename, ColumnKey, ColumnValue))  from #FDATA
```

But when @FDATA has these data:

> 1052  2   100  100008  VIS0  form.PAN_ELIG 4401001 1
>
> 1052  2   100
>   100008
>   VIS0
>   form.PAN_ELIG
>   4401002
>   1
>
> 1052  2 100
>   100008
>   VIS0
>   form.PAN_ELIG
>   4401004
>   0
>
> 1052  2  100
>   100008
>   VIS0
>   form.PAN_ELIG
>   4401005
>   0
>
> 1052  2 100
>   100008
>   VIS0
>   form.PAN_ELIG
>   NULL
>   NULL
>
> 1052  2 100
>   100008
>   VIS0
>   form.PAN_ELIG
>   NULL
>   NULL

The result is 512. Is that a valid checksum?

Because when @FDATA has data like:

> 1064 2 100 100002 VIS1 form.AGG_DEMOG 4502001 agge
>
> 1064
>   2
>   100
>   100002
>   VIS1
>   form.AGG_DEMOG
>   4502003
>   0
>
> 1064
>   2
>   100
>   100002
>   VIS1
>   form.AGG_DEMOG
>   4502006
>   0

The result is always something like this: -785679630

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Any value that fits in an `INT` is a valid checksum. And what does this have to do with C#?

Comment: @JeroenMostert nothing to do... my mistake because my code is in C# but the checksum is calculated in stored procedure